# Is there any way to get random from enum class in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, enum-class

I want to fill a variable with random element from enum class.

So I tried set enum class type to int and pass last enum from enum class to rand:

```cpp
enum class Enumerator: int
{
    en1=0,
    en2,
    en3,
    ensCount
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    auto a=static_cast<Enumerator>(rand()%Enumerator::ensCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Result is "no match for «operator%» (operand types are «int» and «Enumerator»)" error.

Comment: `static_cast<int>(Enumerator::ensCount)` The error message is pretty clear, % works on ints.

Comment: You can cast the `Enumerator::ensCount` to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operands of the built-in modulo (`%`) operator should be integral or ***unscoped*** enumeration type.

`Enumerator` is a [**scoped** enumeration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations).

There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types.
So you have to use `static_cast` to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

```
int divisor = static_cast<int>(Enumerator::ensCount);
srand(time(NULL));
auto a = static_cast<Enumerator>(rand() % divisor);
```